# required attribute is not working in select

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

after button click required attribute is not working.
I have three buttons `btn-insert`, `btn-update` `btn-insertvideo` but after press `btn-insert` it not validate

My code:

```
<form method="POST" id="topic_form" class="form-horizontal well">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
          <select  id="mainCatItem" name="mainCatItem" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="">Select Category</option>}
            option
            <?php foreach($fetchcat as $fetchcategory): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $fetchcategory->main_category_id; ?>"><?php echo $fetchcategory->main_category_name; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
     </div>

      <div class="form-group row mb-0">
       <div class="col-sm-6">
          <Button type="submit" id="btn-insert" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</Button>
          <button type="submit" id="btn-update" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
       </div>
    </div>
    <input id="btn-insertvideo" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
<script>
    $('#btn-insert').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>admin_controller/WebsiteContentController/createtopic",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#topic_form').serialize(),
            dataType:'text',
            success: function(response)
            {
              alert(response);
            }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

I want show require message after click `btn-insert` 
I want to stop that ajax after `btn-insert` click if dopdown is not select

Comment: dont relay on html5 `required` , use server side validation also.

Comment: Where is the `<form>`?

Comment: button not Button

Comment: @JDunken I update my code

Comment: `required` is tested when you submit a form but you are calling `preventDefault` when the submit button is clicked so the button never starts the form submission.

Comment: You are also setting a value for the select by having the first option 'Select Category', the first option should be ''